# VSTS use on premise deployment agent

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I ran out of release/build minutes on VSTS, therefore I configured an on premise agent to run my builds. This is working fine, however I cannot select that agent to be used for deploying my releases.

I tried to follow the following tutorial, however it seems like it is a bit old:

http://vsts-deploy-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Does anyone have experience setting up on premise agents to do the deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to these steps:

1. Open release definition
2. Select `Environments` tab
3. Click `Run on agent`
4. Change Deployment queue in right panel.

[image]